# Properties of invariant polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, polynomials

> Let $\alpha$ be a primitive $k$th root of unity. If $f(z)$ is a complex polynomial of degree $n$ and $f(\alpha^j z) = f(z) $ for all $j \in \mathbb{Z}$ what can we say about $f$?

This type of functions is called invariant functions. I couldn't find a textbook or resource about this topic.

Comment: So have you dealt with the case $k=2$? That ought to give you a good hint for the general case.

Comment: If $\alpha\ne1$, I think the coefficient of each $z^m$ in $f$ must be zero whenever $m$ is not an integer multiple of $k$. That is, $f$ is a polynomial in $z^k$.

Comment: Hint: $\;f(z)+f(\alpha z)+f(\alpha^2 z)+\dots+f(\alpha^{n-1} z)=\dots$

Comment: @dxiv it is equal to $nf(z)$., but does that gice idea about the degree of $f$?

Comment: @Adam_math I meant for an arbitrary polynomial $\,f(z)\,$ in general, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134075/primitive-roots-of-unity) for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $f=f_0+\cdots +f_n$ in its homogeneous pieces.

$f(\alpha^j z)=f(z)$ implies that

$f_t(\alpha^j z)=\alpha^{jt}f_t= f_t$

and so $jt\equiv 0 \bmod k$.

Thus $z^j f= z^k F$

where $F=\sum_{\{t \ : \ jt\equiv 0 \bmod k\}}f_{\frac{jt}{k}}$